# Interpretation VECM

Tags: interpretation, vector-error-correction-model

I am testing two Variables, lets say "A" and "B" that are cointegration of order I(1). I am using a VECM and define "A" as my dependent variable and the VECM says that the significant error correction therm has a Value of  -0.17. So the dependet variable "A" is correction the deviation each periode by 17%. The interpretation is, that "B" is the dominant variable and "A" adjusts to it and it takes around 6 Periods(1/.17) to adjust the error.

But how do I interpret a result where "B" as the depended variable has also a significant error correction therm of -0.14?